# R Shiny Treemap that counts the number of people in each group

Tags: r, shiny

So I'm trying to render a reactive treemap in Shiny.

I have a 'pensions' DF with one row per person that looks like:

```
set.seed(2)
Pensions <- data.frame(ID = c("21000", "23400", "26800","21076", "23490", "169800"),
                  Plan_Name = c("Good Plan", "Great Plan", "Nice Plan", "Bad Plan", "Good Plan", "Great Plan"),
                  Benefit_Type = c("DEFC", "DEFB", "DEFC", "COMBO", "DEFC", "DEFB"),
                  Members = c(43, 563, "5", "12", "43", "563"))
```

Right now I'm making the treemap in a traditional way, where I'm counting "Members":

```
treemap(Pensions, #Your data frame object
        index=c("Benefit_Type"),  
        vSize = ("Members"), 
        type="index", 
        vColor = "Benefit_Type",
)
```

[image: And getting this:]

It's skewed as hell because when I use `vSize = ("Members")` I'm saying: "sum the number of members by benefit type". **How can I instead `count(ID)`?** FYI doing `vSize = count("ID")` doesn't work.

Probably a simple solution but these small variations always cross me up in R. I want to avoid setting a data.frame off my main DF to avoid one being updated while the other is not (if that makes sense).I'm starting from basic and scaling up but I eventually want this treemap from the World Banks' Covid-19 tracker:
[here](http://datatopics.worldbank.org/universal-health-coverage/covid19/)
[image]

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't figure out how to count() so I just made a separate DF and aggregated to the pension plan level. Thanks anyway, those who viewed!